# What kind of phrase is this? [manically across the stage]

Tags: phrases, prepositional-phrases, noun-phrases

In the sentence: At the beginning of the play, the entire cast dances maniacally across the stage. What kind of phrase is [manically across the stage]?
Is it an adverb phrase, prepositional phrase or (as some of my schoolmates think) a noun phrase? 
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: It is not one phrase but two, both playing adverbial roles: "The cast dances [in this manner] [at this location]."

Comment: @StoneyB you might as well put that in as an answer. I doubt anyone has much more to say on the matter, and whether they do or not, that does answer the question adequately.

Comment: I think this question is a bit basic for ELU, so I've closevoted as General Reference. Offhand the only way I can think of to use a *noun (phrase)* after a verb like ***dance*** is something along the lines of ["Nijinsky danced Swan Lake"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Nijinsky+danced+Swan+Lake%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @JonHanna As you wish.

Comment: @FumbleFingers can you think of a general reference that would aid answering this question? I think it would be reasonable to comment with a helpful link in this case because I can't think just how I'd google for it myself.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: I don't see the point. I don't want to see questions at this level on ELU, and StoneyB's first comment seems quite enough for a "helpful, polite" response prior to closing it. But I'd have thought *any* dictionary would clarify that *manically* is an adverb. The fact that *across the stage* is really a prepositional phrase rather than an adverbial one seems a bit advanced in the context of an OP who thought it might be a *noun phrase*. Any again, any dictionary will confirm that *across* is a preposition.

Comment: @FumbleFingers well, maybe a move to ELL or a close instead? As it was, it sat under unanswered questions with a perfectly adequate answer in a comment.

Comment: @Jon: Yeah, well my comment was by way of explanation to OP of why I was closevoting (I was too lazy to bother adding my customary "should be on ELL" advice). If OP had gone to the trouble of signing up with an actual *name*, I probably would have added the advice *and* flagged the question to ask if the mods would consider migrating it to ELL (where I'd be more than happy to see questions like this).

Comment: @FF We need a 'This question is off-topic as it is rather basic for ELU' option. Oh, and _dance_ takes cognate objects (he danced the dance of the dead) and hyponymic objects (he danced a tango / foxtrot). I'm not too happy with the dropped 'in' [Swan Lake], though the resulting construction does seem to be used nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

It is not one phrase but two, both playing adverbial roles:

> The cast dances [in this manner] [at this location].

*Maniacally* is an adverb; *across the stage* is a preposition phrase.

Comment: Likewise, *manically* and *maniacally* are not one word but two.